# Generate a new row, with a new GUID, from the MongoDB shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell, nosql

I have some documents in a MongoDB collection with a GUID-type key, and I would like to be able to copy them to a new row, with a new GUID, using the shell.  I tried this:

```
db.schedules.find().forEach(function(x) { 
    x._id = null; 
    db.schedules.save(x); 
});
```

I expected the **_id** field to auto-generate after I set it to null, but of course that was naive.  How, if at all, could I go about generating a new GUID in the shell?

**UPDATE**

Apparently not possible to generate a GUID from the shell.  I ended up writing a mini-script in C# so as to use the Mongo C# driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
x._id = new ObjectId();
db.schedules.insert(x);
```

You can also do:

```
delete x._id;
db.schedules.insert(x);
```

Comment: Well, that works, but of course the ID is an ObjectId **ObjectId("4f963746ee633c3aa4a71a60")** rather than the C# GUID **BinData(3,"+Wgv1RJhr0K5/qbi3McvlQ==")**.  I suppose that is a feature of the C# driver, and I'll have to use that for this task.

Comment: Yeah, the shell doesn't have a way to generate GUIDs. If you have a GUID value you can set it in the shell via the BinData wrapper as you show (with base 64), but it can't generate new ones for you. (sorry, missed that you wanted a GUID)

Comment: I suspect that you could write a Javascript function to create your GUID and register the function in the MongoDB shell.

Comment: Yeah, you probably could. But it might be difficult to make the GUID generator work the same way as the C# GUID generator.